# Exclude third party assemblies from getting copied through Post-Build commands

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly

I am referring to third party assemblies in my running assembly. All these third party assemblies are in some Library folder and I am directly adding the reference from the library folder.

However, when I build my running assembly, it copies those files physically from library folder to its own debug/bin folder.

Now, I have another project which copies all the files from my running assembly's debug/bin folder to its own folder called "Plugins.". The problem here is that All the third party assemblies which were initially copied from library folder to the debug/bin folder are getting copied with it.

I do not want that to happen. How can I stop these third party libraries from getting copied in all the places in my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring up the properties window of your reference and set the property: `Copy Local` to `false`
[image]